# Turning a label into a global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, global-variables

i need to get a value from a stepper into a global variable.
 i first tried to do this,

```
NSInteger MYGlobalVariable =0;


-(IBAction)time:(UIStepper *)sender {
int value = [sender value];
MYGlobalVariable = (int)value;}


reloadtimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:MYGlobalVariable target:self selector:@selector(WebViewLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];}
```

the last part of that code was a timer from my webview, but the gvariable wont change with the stepper, so is there a way this works or ..

i could do the stepper with a label and then convert that into the global variable? but i dont know how to do that either

Comment: I've been starring this question for several minutes, but I still haven't found the relation to Xcode.

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be a global variable, and not just an instance variable? Do you need access to it outside of whatever viewController this is?

Comment: @mjvotaw yes and no, i was going to do it from a different view controller but i just need it to work either way really

Comment: Save it in your standardUserDefaults and get it as you need it. Answer below will work

Answer (score 1):

for save a user setting, use:

for save:

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [pref setInteger:integerStepValue forKey:@"StepperValue"];
 [pref synchronize];
```

for read

```
int myStepper = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"StepperValue"] intValue] ;
```

Comment: save the variable when intercetate the stepper changes. I don't know you proget, you have posted only a IBAction, but i don't know what are you doing!;) explane your proget with more detail and code, i'll help you! The better way to do this is by using delegate method, but may be is too early to use for you if you are newest!